# Connected set in normed space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I have this exercise:

"let $E$ be a normed space and $X\subset E$ $$X~\text{connected}~\Longleftrightarrow \forall A\subset X,~\text{such that} A\neq\emptyset, A\neq X~\text{we have}~ Fr(A)\neq \emptyset $$

I don't understand where we use the fact that $E$ is a normed space?

Thank you.

Comment: Well it's certainly not true in any space.  Doesn't seem true in a discrete space.

Comment: Nowhere, provided the boundary is understood with respect to the subspace $X$. The characterisation is valid for every topological space. $X$ is connected if and only if the only open and closed subsets are $\varnothing$ and $X$, and $A$ is open and closed if and only if its boundary is empty.

Comment: @DanielFischer so this execise is correct for every topological space

Comment: Provided the boundary is taken with respect to $X$. If the boundary is taken with respect to $E$, it is false: e.g. $X = (0,1) \cup (2,3) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not connected, but every non-empty subset of $X$ has non-empty boundary in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what is the relation with normed space ?

Comment: @DanielFischer What can be the question to use the fact that $E$ is normed ?thank you

Comment: None, zilch, rien. The characterisation of connected subspaces is completely unrelated to the ambient space, only the subspace topology is relevant.